# Custom dashboard using application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have to create external custom dashboard in application Insights like ARM template,
If I provided the file to client they can easily used it and create custom dashboard for them,
How can I create my own custom template to capture app insights data or own custom dashboard?

Comment: Public (not private) dashboard is ARM object and can be created through ARM template.

Comment: Can you provide some more information what you are exactly looking for ?

Comment: Actually , I have to create a JSON template file, if I provided that JSON template file to client they can deployed it and create the same dashboard on any application insights. Is it Ok  ?

Comment: Did you tried any workaround ? If please provide that information so that community will help you to solve your issue